# Only last of components get details filled

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working on an app with cryptocurrencies, so right now I have 2 components:
MyCoins:

```
Vue.component('mycoins',{
data() {
    return {
        coins: [],
    }
},
template: `
    <ul class="coins">
        <coin v-for="(coin, key) in coins" :coin="coin.coin_name" :key="coin.coin_name"></coin>
    </ul>
`,
methods: {
    getStats() {
        self = this;
        axios.get('api/user/coins').then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data.coins);
            self.coins = response.data.coins;
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.getStats();
}
```

})

On url 'api/user/coins' I get this data:

```
{"coins":
[{"id":1,"coin_name":"ethereum","user_id":1,"buy_price_usd":"341.44000","buy_price_btc":"0.14400","created_at":"2017-09-25 20:40:20","updated_at":"2017-09-25 20:40:20"},
    {"id":2,"coin_name":"bitcoin","user_id":1,"buy_price_usd":"12.00000","buy_price_btc":"14.00000","created_at":"2017-09-25 21:29:18","updated_at":"2017-09-25 21:29:18"},
    {"id":3,"coin_name":"ethereum-classic","user_id":1,"buy_price_usd":"33.45000","buy_price_btc":"3.00000","created_at":"2017-09-25 21:49:50","updated_at":"2017-09-25 21:49:50"},{"id":4,"coin_name":"lisk","user_id":1,"buy_price_usd":"23.33000","buy_price_btc":"0.50000","created_at":"2017-09-25 21:51:26","updated_at":"2017-09-25 21:51:26"}]}
```

Then I have this component: Coin:

```
Vue.component('coin',{
data() {
    return {
        thisCoin: this.coin,
        coinData: {
            name: "",
            slug: "",
            image: "https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/32x32/.png",
            symbol: "",
            price_eur: "",
            price_usd: "",
        }
    }
},
props: ['coin'],
template: `
    <li class="coin">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-lg-2 branding">
                <img :src="this.coinData.image">
                <small>{{this.coinData.name}}</small>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-lg-8 holdings">
                <p>11.34 <span>{{this.coinData.symbol}}</span></p>
                <p>$ {{this.coinData.price_usd * 3}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-lg-2 price">
                <p>{{this.coinData.price_usd}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="edit col-lg-2">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <p>Edit</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>Delete</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
`,
methods: {
    getCoin: function(name) {
        self = this;
        axios.get('api/coin/' + name).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            self.coinData.name = response.data.coin.name;
            self.coinData.price_usd = response.data.coin.price_usd;
            self.coinData.price_eur = response.data.coin.pride_eur;
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.getCoin(this.coin);
}
```

})

On url 'api/coin/{name}' I get this data:

```
{"coin":{"slug":"lisk","name":"Lisk","symbol":"LSK","rank":14,"price_usd":"6.15510","price_btc":"0.00156","24h_volume_usd":null,"market_cap_usd":"99999.99999","available_supply":"99999.99999","total_supply":"99999.99999","percent_change_1h":"0.10000","percent_change_24h":"6.78000","percent_change_7d":"-5.64000","last_updated":1506385152,"price_eur":"5.19166","24h_volume_eur":null,"market_cap_eur":"99999.99999","created_at":"2017-09-25 00:06:27","updated_at":"2017-09-26 00:23:02"}}
```

But as of right now, only the last component gets the details filled (name, price_usd, price_eur, etc.), but not the first 3 ones.

Here is the video of loading the page: https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/BreakableSlimHammerkop - You can see it goes trough all the coins it should pass to the first three components. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to me the components are ok, does the api test ok? https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/mBRXrb

Comment: Is it possible your `self` variable is shared across all components? I do not see a `var` or a `let` so ... Alternatively, you can avoid the self-shuffle by using arrow functions: `axios.get(...).then(response => { this.coinData.name = response.data.coin.name; ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because the `self` variables you've declared in your `getStats()` and `getCoin()` methods are bound to the `window` object, and not properly scoped to each method. A simple fix would be to replace each `self = this;` statement with `var self = this;`.

Let me explain.

When you declare a new variable without using the `var`, `let` or `const` keywords, the variable is added to the global scope object, which in this case is the `window` object. You can find more info about this JavaScript behaviour here https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/ or check the var docs on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Comment: Thank you! I used var self = this; in one of my previous project, but totally forgot about the var, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't directly reassign data value because Vue cannot detect property additions and rerender view. You should do it via `Vue.set` or `this.$set` like this:

```
self.$set(self.coinData, 'name', response.data.coin.name)
...
```